# Having 50 buttons inside a view (all of them with a target added to them) - performance optimisation?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, optimization

I have about 50 buttons inside one of my views. Every button has a method it calls when touched. Sometimes (not all of the time, I couldn't really actively reproduce it) , I noticed the whole UI is getting laggy and it stutters. Are there too many buttons? Or too many targets I add to the buttons?

The thing is, I don't need to show all buttons at once (31 buttons is the maximum that is visible at the same time). Right now, I'm creating all 50 buttons and just hide them (I kind of move them out of the view). Would it make a difference to delete the buttons and redraw them when they should become visible again?

Or should I just deactivate the method call when they're touched (then the device doesn't have to check 50 buttons for every touch).

Alternatively, I could create the buttons without a `target`. Instead, I would add a `tap gesture recogniser` and use the touch location to calculate which button was tapped. This way, there's only one thing the device needs to check per tap.

There are many possibilities, but I'm not sure what's the best way to improve performance. I'm still a rookie when it comes to performance optimization. I have no idea if 50 buttons generally are too much to be handled properly.

Below, I added a sample code of how I add the buttons. There are more `loops` like this, only slightly different (basically they're all just adding buttons).

It would be great if someone could tell me a little bit about the performance of `swift`/`ios` regarding the amount of `views` and `targets` it can properly handle. I looked through some articles on the internet, but all I found was content about optimising the `compile`process and stuff. I don't think, that's what I want. Maybe I use the wrong keywords.

Thanks!

```
    for i in 1...31 {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: CGFloat(i-1) * buttonHeight, width: width, height: buttonHeight)
        button.backgroundColor = AppTheme.baseBlack
        button.setTitle(String(i), for: .normal)

        daysScrollView.addSubview(button)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dayButtonTapped(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    }
```

Comment: Sounds like a good use for a UICollectionView.

Comment: Oh, I didn't thinks about that. Good idea

Comment: I'd say `UITableView` might fit in here if it's just a vertical list of buttons. Make sure you look into cell reuse (`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`).

Comment: Hm, with all this in mind (when I wrote the question, I did not think about this at all) I think I should add that some of the buttons are side by side. It's not just a vertical list.

Comment: What about using a horizontal `UIScrollView`containing a `UITableView`for each "column"?